# React Native Geolocation Not updating in Simulator

Tags: react-native, geolocation, react-native-ios

I am in the process of building a mobile application that relies heavily on the user's current location. Until recently, I could easily enter custom coordinates into my simulator Debug -> Location and have my app reflect that change. I recently upgraded to react-native 0.41.1 and my app can no longer register the change in location.

My stack:

react: 15.4.2
react-native: 0.41.1
xcode: 8.2.1
mac os sierra
ios 10.2

My code:

```
componentDidMount() {
    //this._getUserLocation();
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        var initialPosition = JSON.stringify(position);
        console.log(initialPosition);
      },
      (error) => alert(JSON.stringify(error)),
      {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000}
    );
  }
```

I have all the correct location permissions in my info.plist, and I have tried numerous ways of removing, re-adding, removing from location services in settings and reallowing the permission, etc. But I continue to get the same results.

My app will load whatever the Debug -> Location is set to on boot, and then not register any change I make to simulate a new location.

example:

On boot it loads:
{"coords":    {"speed":0,"longitude":-122.0312186,"latitude":37.33233141,"accuracy":5,"he ading":-1,"altitude":0,"altitudeAccuracy":-1},"timestamp":1488260204384.006}

That's Apple HQ. I then go to Debug -> Location and change to custom coordinates, reload my app, and I get the same output. This used to not be the case. I can try any new coordinates and it's always the same. Though sometimes, if I change the coordinates and reboot, it will load with the new coordinates, and then the problem repeats itself.

Changing the maximumAge value has no effect.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated. I've been at this issue for a few weeks now and totally stuck.

Thanks in advance.